# How can I break external links in PowerPoint 2007 but keep the charts editable (not images)?

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I have created a few charts in an Excel file and then pasted them as links into PowerPoint (PPT). Whenever I update the excel file, PPT updates automatically.

However when I break the links, the charts in PowerPoint become images. I need the charts to be normal charts which are editable. I need to send the PowerPoint to someone else but I don't want to give them the linked Excel file. Also, I need them to be able to edit the charts.

Answer (score 0):

Charts are just a form of representation of the values.
If you want to be able to edit chart you need to provide a values in a second spreadsheet. You do not have to give an additional excel file - just copy the necessary values to second spreadsheet and point the chart link to use this newly added values. It will work the same as from external file.

there is no way of keeping the chart without values that created it while still being able to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that actually doesn't solve my problem.



I don't mind if the data for each chart is in individual spreadsheets (as they normally are if you create the chart in ppt). However, I don't want to have all the charts in one spreadsheet that links to ppt. 

Is there a way that once I break the links I can make the charts stay as individual charts (linking to separate datasheets) rather than images?

Thanks